# Laravel Relationships with multiple foreign key and pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am quite new to laravel, I have four tables, employees, jobs, applied_jobs, and employee_profile_picture:
 [image: enter image description here][1]

Employee and Jobs has many to many relationships

Employee Model:

```
class Employee extends Authenticatable {

    public function employeeProfilePhoto() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EmployeeProfilePhoto', 'employee_id');
    }

    public function jobsApplied() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Job::class, 'jobs_applieds', 'employee_id', 'job_id')
            ->withPivot('cover_letter', 'cv_path','created_at')
            ->orderBy('pivot_created_at','desc');
    }
}
```

Jobs Model:

```
class Job extends Model {

    public function appliedByEmployees() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class, 'jobs_applieds', 'job_id', 'employee_id')
            ->withPivot('cover_letter', 'cv_path','employee_application_status');
    }

}
```

Employee Profile Photo Model:

```
class EmployeeProfilePhoto extends Model {

    protected $table = 'employees_profile_photos';

    public function employeePhoto() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'employee_id');
    }
}
```

I want to get all the employees and their profile picture who have applied for the job where employer_id matches to some id in jobs table. I want to use laravel eloquent. How can this be achieved

Comment: where, in a controller? what have you tried? in the model employee?

Comment: @Erubiel $candidates = Job::with('appliedByEmployees.employeeProfilePhoto')  ->where('jobs.employer_id',$currentEmployer->id)
                        
                          
                        ->get(); I tried this in controller

Comment: do you want it on a single query, if you are going to iterate over candidates, as in foreach($candidate on $candidates) you can access the candidate relations like employeeProfilePhoto

Comment: also, your employeeProfilePhoto, is defined as a hasMany relation...which would bring more a set of rows, instead of a given row, making it ambiguous.

Comment: single query would be better as i need to get other data also from employee and other table with relationships with employee like employee_phone in same query

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter by specific id:

```
$employee = Employee::whereHas('jobsApplied', function ($query) use ($someId) {
    $query->where('employee_id', $someId);
})
->with('employeePhoto')
->get();
```

If you want only employees that have applied for a job:

```
$employee = Employee::whereHas('jobsApplied')
    ->with('employeePhoto')
    ->get();
```

[`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) its an eloquent function that checks the relationship existence in your case it will get only employees that have applied for a job, or you can subquery the condition based on a specific need for instance employeee id.

Comment: why are you calling load before you called get? usually you'd use `with` before calling get. load is what you use after you already have fetched the models.

Comment: @Tschallacka good point with that, just switched to `with instead` thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following answer

```
Employee::with(['employeeProfilePhoto', 'jobsApplied'])->get();
```

I don't know what your problem.

Comment: What are the columns in jobs table?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like the following to get all employees with their profile photos where an employee has been applied for a job and matches the `employer_id` in `jobs` table:

```
$employer_id = 'get the employer_id...';

$result = Employee::whereHas('jobsApplied', function($query) use ($employer_id) {
    $query->where('employer_id', $employer_id);
})->with('employeeProfilePhoto', 'jobsApplied')->get();
```

Comment: I get Employee  and profile photo  how do  I get job details and pivot tables details

Comment: You should get the `jobsApplied ` deails as well, notice the `with('jobsApplied')`.